# Why is Firefox Combobox spread out (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firefox, razor

In my MVC solution for a helpdesk, I have multiple comboboxes throughout.  In both IE and Chrome they look fine; however, in firefox they look terrible.

Here is example code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, "Select Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

here is a pic of what the combobox looks like on the different browsers:

[image]

and here is my css:

```
.form-control:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}

.form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}

.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}

.form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #999999;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #555555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
          transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
```

Comment: Something in the CSS perhaps?  The markup alone won't do this.

Comment: Hi @David - I just added my CSS (I think all that you may need).

Comment: With bootstrap 3.3.6 CSS  and your style block alone, I can't reproduce this in Firefox.  There must be some other CSS getting applied to the <option> tags inside of the <select>.